# Flutter Autocomplete with custom value if there is no option

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, package, widget

Newbie here. For the last couple days, I tried to find a way to make an autocomplete form which we can also input custom value if no option is in exact match. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
Autocomplete<String>(
              optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                  return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                }
                return brandsList.where((String option) {
                  return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                })
                //How can I also return textEditingValue for custom input 
                //if no exact match on brandLists were to found. 
                //and have something like "add lenovo as a new brand".
                ;
              },
              onSelected: (String selection) {
                print('You just selected $selection');
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var _selectedLocation2= '';

Autocomplete<String>(
              optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                  return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                }
                return _kOptions.where((option) {
                  var result = option
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                  return result;
                });
              },
              displayStringForOption: (value) => value,
              fieldViewBuilder: ((context, _selectedLocation, focusNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted) =>
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (val) => _selectedLocation2 = val,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      controller: _selectedLocation,
                      focusNode: focusNode,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter location",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
              onSelected: (String selection) {
                _selectedLocation2 = selection;
              },
            )
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.  Include text that explains the code and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add the fieldViewBuilder property inside the autocomplete, something like this:

```
fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
            FocusNode fieldFocusNode,
            VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
          return TextFormField(
            controller: fieldTextEditingController,
            focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              isDense: true,
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            ),                
          );
```

This helps you to have the controller of the TextField and do with the information that is entered what you want

Answer (score 0):

```dart
dummy() {
      return brandsList.where((String option) {
        return option
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
        .contains(textEditingValue.text);
        });
      }
        
    var tt = dummy().toList();
                
//If the list has data, data will be displayed from the List, else typed data will be displayed.
    if (tt.isNotEmpty) {
      return brandsList.where((String option) {
        return option
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
        .contains(textEditingValue.text);
      });
    } else {
      return {textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase().toString()};
    }
```

The dummy function returns all the data that matches from the list, we will convert the data to list. If the list is empty then we will return the text typed by user, else normally the data from the list will be displayed.